# How can I modify my Google Web Apps Script to work with my Transposed Google Sheets Data

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, transpose

I have a Google Web App Script that fetches some Google Sheets data and returns a JSON string.
The spreadsheet "oldSpreadsheetTab" first row is a "header" (example: FIRST NAME; LAST NAME; AGE. And each row below that represents a Record with its cells of corresponding data.
The script works fine when the spreadsheet is organized this way ("oldSpreadsheetTab"). But when I transpose and the columns become rows and rows become columns ("newSpreadsheetTab"), it does not work; as I expected. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to mod my script to create the same output with the transposed spreadsheet data.
Also, I **do not** need my script to transpose programmatically.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
// JSON FROM "oldSpreadsheetTab" // CORRECT //

[{
"firstName":"Adam"
"lastName":"ofEden"
"theirAge":"One"
}
{
"firstName":"Eve"
"lastName":"ofEden"
"theirAge":"One"
}
{
"firstName":"Snake"
"lastName":"inTheGrass"
"theirAge":"Infinity"
}]

// JSON FROM "oldSpreadsheetTab" // CORRECT // END

// JSON FROM "newSpreadsheetTab" // INCORRECT //

[{
"firstName":"lastName"
"lastName":"ofEden"
"theirAge":"ofEden"
}
{
"firstName":"theirAge"
"lastName":"One"
"theirAge":"One"
}]

// JSON FROM "newSpreadsheetTab" // INCORRECT // END
```

// MY SPREADSHEET

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FU1gDa55YIpo67O_rOA5OrenPBCWXw72sepZDI8-HMI/edit?usp=sharing

// MY SPREADSHEET // END

// MY GOOGLE WEB APP SCRIPT @ https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxP619HVQSSZ_mEgfbxSeYnxtWRJr0ZysjbZLuwa4Mq_P3_uxs/exec

```
// Access Data
function doGet(e){
  
// From Spreadsheet  
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FU1gDa55YIpo67O_rOA5OrenPBCWXw72sepZDI8-HMI/edit#gid=1012037872");
  
// From Tab
// var importantDataTab = ss.getSheetByName("oldSpreadsheetTab");
 var importantDataTab = ss.getSheetByName("newSpreadsheetTab");

// Access Returns
 return getImportantData(importantDataTab); 

}

// Identify Specific Data from Sheet Tabs
function getImportantData(importantDataTab){
  var importantData = {};
  var importantDataArray = [];
  
// Read Specified Data from 2nd Row, 1st Column to Last Row, Last Column  
  var importantRows = importantDataTab.getRange(2,1,importantDataTab.getLastRow()-1, importantDataTab.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  for(var i = 0, l= importantRows.length; i<l ; i++){
    var theRow = importantRows[i];
    var theRowData = {};
    
    theRowData['firstName'] = theRow[0];
    theRowData['lastName'] = theRow[1];
    theRowData['theirAge'] = theRow[2];

// Create Data Array  
    importantDataArray.push(theRowData);
    
  }  
    
// Extract Data Array
  importantData = importantDataArray;
  
// Convert Data Array to String
  var result = JSON.stringify(importantData);
  
// Finalize
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  
}
```

// SPREADSHEET SCREENSHOT BEFORE TRANSPOSING //
[image]

// SPREADSHEET SCREENSHOT AFTER TRANSPOSING //
[image]

Comment: What do you see when you transpose the data?

Comment: @Jescanellas, sorry.. what do you mean? do you mean 'what do i see' other than what i posted above?  I will add screenshots of the spreadsheets (before transposing and after transposing), if that helps.  ?